# Swagger 2.0 : Array in header of a response

Tags: arrays, header, response, swagger

Anyone know why this syntax is not supported ?

The pagination-links send an error and I can't find a way to declare them as an array :

```
responses:
    200:
      description: An array of screens
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Screens'
      headers:
        content-range:
          type: string
          format: '[min]-[max]/[Total]'
          description: 'Range of the element returned by the api like 1-7/1000'
        pagination-links:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Link'
```

Your help would be really appreciated,

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you post your `Link` definition?

Comment: Sure :         Link:
    type: object
    properties:
      type:
        type: string
        enum: ["self","next","previous","first","last"]
      format:
        type: string
        format: uri
      description:
        type: string
        description: Pagination links